When should we use $\sigma/\epsilon$ and $\sigma/2\epsilon$?

I was doing a question, in this i have to find distance between proton and plate.. so i use work energy theorm ie change in ke is net work done..
so as for electric field i use gauss law and taken gauss surface as cylinder.. through which i find electric field '$\sigma/2\epsilon$'.....
so
$$KE = qEd$$
$$(E= \sigma/2\epsilon)$$
and got my ans 80 mm but the real ans is 40 mm....
after going through solution i come to know that E=$\sigma/\epsilon$.. but why?
this Electric field is used when there is no electric field on other side.. but other side also have electric field.. so my solution must be right...



Some comments removed. Please remember that comments are not for answering questions.
